# Which data type should I use for a parliament voting schema?

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I'm designing a small logical model of a database in Oracle Data Modeler. I have basically 4 entities: "Deputy", "Act", "Political Party" and "Voting". I'm struggling with setting up the entity Voting. Every Deputy can voter for, against an Act or abstain from voting. Should I use a list in a domain? 
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, I might go for some sort of integer:

- 1, vote for
- 0, abstain
- -1, vote against
- NULL no vote (which might be different from abstain)

That way, you could add up the tallies of the positive and negative votes together (to get the net votes) or separately (to get the votes individually).